# Arcpy label white color

Tags: arcpy, labeling

I have this label expression within a function that works great. I want to turn the color to white.

```
lblClass.expression = '"{}" + [OBJECTID] +  "{}"'.format("<FNT size = '10'>","</FNT>")
```

this the RGB colors for white...

```
<CLR red='255' green='255' blue='255'>
```

I am unsure on how to format this together

Comment: not tested but normally you can simply concatenate format("<CLR red='255' green='255' blue='255'><FNT size = '10'>","</FNT></CLR>")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @radouxju has said, you can link the different tags together:

```
lblClass.expression = '"{}" + [OBJECTID] +  "{}"'.format("<FNT size = '10'><CLR red='255' green='255' blue='255'>","</CLR></FNT>")
```

which should output something like `<FNT size = '10'><CLR red='255' green='255' blue='255'>[OBJECTID]</CLR></FNT>`

Comment: so the "<FNT size = '10'><CLR red='255' green='255' blue='255'>" opens the coloring and font tags? and then I have to close it with"</CLR></FNT>" ? like HTML style?

Comment: yes, that's right

Answer (score 2):

you just need to open and close your color tags in the expression

```
lblClass.expression = '"{}" + [OBJECTID] +  "{}"'.format("<CLR red = '255' green = '255' blue = '255'><FNT size = '10'>","</FNT></CLR>")
```